# Performance of member pointer vs if else

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the following class:

```
class A {
private:
   int do_work_internal(const & Parameter p1, const Parameter & p2);
public:
   int do_work(const Parameter & p1, const Parameter&  p2, bool p1_first) {
       if (p1_first) {
          return do_work_internal(p1, p2);
       else {
          return do_work_internal(p2, p1);
       }
   }
};
```

basically class `A` takes in 2 parameters and does some calculation, however, the **order** of the 2 parameters is importance and determined by the bool `p1_first`. Since `do_work` gets called very frequently and `p1_first` for a pair of `p1`, `p2` almost never changes, I'm thinking of modifying `A` to the following:

```
class A {
private:
    int do_work_internal(const Parameter& p1, const Parameter& p2);
    vector<pair<Parameter*>> param_orders; // added
public:
    int do_work (int parameter_pair_index) {
       const auto & params = param_orders[parameter_pair_index];
       do_work_internal(*params.first, *params.second);
    }
};
```

in this new version, I added an array that memorizes the order for each pair of `p1` and `p2`, and inside `do_work` I simply just pass the parameters to `do_work_internal`.

my question is : given the fact

1. `Parameter` orders rarely change
2. There are about 1000 `Parameter` objects
3. `do_work` is called 100+ times / second
4. even 0.5 micro-second improvement is good to have

is the second class has a faster performance than the first ?

Comment: The only real way to answer is is to profile both versions. I expect a decent C++ compiler to optimize both to the point where the gains are negligible.

Comment: I don't think you have saved any time by doing this. An if-statement can be represented with a single machine instruction, whereas your second approach is going to utilise atleast more than one instruction before the function call.

Comment: Since the calling code always knows the correct parameter order, let the calling code supply the parameters in correct order. This has nothing to do with execution efficiency but with code clarity. It's just silly to have to supply the parameters in an undesired order plus a boolean saying that one really wants them in the opposite order.

Comment: Also, a class-that-does is a code smell. Classes don't *do*. Unless it's a functor class, which this doesn't look like.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf the real code is indeed what you suggested: the caller supplies parameters in correct order, but the caller still has to determine the order every time.